# Почему макрос S_ISDIR в Linux возвращает все файлы как директории

Tags: c++, linux

Хочу рекурсивно просмотреть директорию и найти все текстовые файлы. Для этого использую такой код

```
while ((entry = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
    stat(entry->d_name, &st);
    if (S_ISREG(st.st_mode)) {
        printf("%20s\t%d\n", entry->d_name, st.st_size);
    }
    if (S_ISDIR(st.st_mode))    {
        DIR* dir;
        dir = opendir(entry->d_name);
        cout << "dir" << entry->d_name << endl;
        cout << "st "<< st.st_mode << endl;
        read_dir(dir);
    }
}
```

но по какой-то причине при просмотре директории на каждом файле и папке выполняется `if (S_ISDIR(st.st_mode))`,
а `if (S_ISREG(st.st_mode))` всегда **false**.

Comment: А успешность выполнения `stat` преверяли? Может оно у вас не выполняется вообще, а вы потом разглядываете один и тот же мусор в `st.st_mode`.

Comment: Вероятно stat() с ошибкой возвращается (==-1, perror()), к примеру из-за того что не полное имя передаётся или относительное не из той директории. Ещё стоит пропустить ".", ".." имена.

Comment: Там по коду вообще нигде ошибки не проверяются

Comment: проверил, stat() выполняется без ошибки...(

Comment: Что насчёт других комментариев (исключите `"."`, `".."` добавьте проверку ошибок ко всем функциям)? Приведите полный пример кода, который ошибку показывает. [mcve]

Comment: благодарю за помощь) разобрался, все работает))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Вашем коде есть, как минимум, три ошибки:

1) Нет в приведённом тексте такой функции: "read_dir(dir)". Есть "readdir(dir)".

2) Вы неправильно формируете имя файлов текущего уровня - отсутствует верхняя часть пути к файлу. А при обработке элементов, которые являются поддиректориями, эта ошибка повторяется дважды!

3) Ну и при анализе подкаталога Вы делаете нечто не очень мне понятное - видимо, read_dir(dir) - это Ваша функция, которая должна изображать РЕКУРСИВНУЮ обработку? Ну так и пишите её РЕКУРСИВНО !

Я не стал заморачиваться с полной переделкой Вашего кода на рекурсивный вариант, а по первым двум пунктам, код должен быть такой:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    DIR *d;
    struct dirent *entry;
    struct stat st;
    char dir_name[256];
    char wrk[256];
    int rc;

    if (argc > 1) {
        strcpy(dir_name, argv[1]);
    } else { 
        strcpy(dir_name, ".");
    }

    d = opendir(dir_name);
    if (d == NULL) {
        printf("Ошибка при открытии директории %s\n", dir_name);
        exit(-1);
    }

    while ((entry = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
        strcpy(wrk, dir_name);
        strcat(wrk, "/");
        strcat(wrk,entry->d_name); 
        rc = stat(wrk, &st);
        if (rc != 0 ) {
        printf("Ошибка при вызове stat('%s')\n", wrk);
        exit(-1);
        }
        if (S_ISREG(st.st_mode)) {
        printf("%20s\t%ld\n", entry->d_name, st.st_size);
        }
        if (S_ISDIR(st.st_mode))    {
        DIR* dir;
        dir = opendir(entry->d_name);
        printf("dir %s\n", entry->d_name);
        printf("st %x\n", st.st_mode);
        readdir(dir);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: И ещё забыл написать - ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО организуйте особую обработку элементов "." и "..".

Comment: благодарю, разобрался) все работает))